# Controls with bitmaps

Tags: c, winapi, controls

How can I make a control using bitmaps which changes when I drag with the mouse (e.g. a rotating knob)? And this using the Win32 API?

Comment: You will have to do this yourself by handling mouse events and updating the display. If you have any specific questions about this, just update your question and we can help you with that.

Comment: Yes, I was so far. But how? Do I have to use a static control with a bitmap on it? And how can I handle the mouse events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write code to recognize the WM_MOUSEWHEEL message in your control's window procedure.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a typical loop you'll see in simple games. It's not good practice but a good basis to build upon:

```
while(!quit) {
    while(evt = events_left_for_processing) {
        react_to_event(evt);
    }

    draw_frame();
}
```

Pay special attention to the second "while", it is better to do it like this than to do an "if", you'll be able to process combined events more accurately.

After a while you may need time-based physics and it becomes more complicated (using accumulators).. A sample from a rather simple game I was writing:

```
/* Time-based animation loop.
 * Accumulator idea picked from an article by Glenn Fiedler on gafferongames.com */
while(!done) {
    /* Input */
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&evt)) {
        window_event(evt, &done);
    }

    /* Physics */
    newTime = time();
    deltaTime = newTime - currentTime;

    if(deltaTime > 0.0f) {
        currentTime = newTime;
        accumulator += deltaTime;
        while(accumulator >= dt) {
            window_update(t, dt);
            accumulator -= dt;
            t += dt;
        }
    }

#ifdef FPS_CAPPED
    drawTime = newTime - currentDrawTime;
    /* Draw */
    if(drawTime >= FPS_CAPPED) {
        currentDrawTime = newTime;
#endif
        window_draw();
        SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
#ifdef FPS_CAPPED
    }
#endif
}
```

`window_update` etc are generalized functions (they execute a function in the game state, using function pointers).
In your case, the transformation of the square would be changed in the *event* handler, which catches mouse_move events and has a state for catching mouse_press/release events. In the *update* you would change the square's position/etc data. In the *draw* routine you would blit the square. (unless you use other frameworks like OpenGL which use matrix transforms in the render pipeline)